# How do I escape a Swift doc comment Callout?

Tags: swift, xcode, documentation, escaping, headerdoc

I have the following doc comment in Swift:

```
/**
- Trace
- &darr;
- Debug
- &darr;
- Information
- &darr;
- Warning
- &darr;
- Error
*/
```

The line that says "Warning" does not render in Xcode because "- warning" is a keyword callout in swift doc comments. How can I escape the callout?

Answer (score 0):

Not a perfect solution, but you could surround Warning with backticks (`).  This will change its display style slightly:

```
/**
 - Trace
 - &darr;
 - Debug
 - &darr;
 - Information
 - &darr;
 - `Warning`
 - &darr;
 - Error
 */
```

[image: Comments]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a zero-width space (`&#8203;`) before the keyword:

```swift
/**
 - Trace
 - &darr;
 - Debug
 - &darr;
 - Information
 - &darr;
 - &#8203;Warning
 - &darr;
 - Error
 */
```

[image: screenshot of rendered documentation]